# post/send updates or messages to fans(who likes website) not as user

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have simple website for auctioning.I want people who likes my website needs to be informed about any new auctioning. And sending messages or post updates to their news feed or post on their wall when they win the auction. The user can also share the story of a new auction to their friends.

For this Do I need separate canvas app ?

I went through the documentation http://csharpsdk.org/. Also I read official graph api docs.

I thought there will be lists of classes in a namespace and its use. Lists of methods, properties in a class and its uses and explanation for parameters.

I cant find such documentation for facebook c# sdk. In official docs they only have 5 articles in which 3 are [TO-DO].

- I cant find what are the classes are there?
- what are the purpose of
  the particular class or method ?

  For informing about new Auctioning and winning news what can be used ?

  1. sending mesages
  2. post on their news feed
  3. post on their wall(or timeline)

I found how to post on behalf of the user. But I need to inform the fans of my website when there is a new auctioning. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> Winning an auction

About generating user actions on their walls about winning auctions and stuff, you need to look at facebook [open graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

> For informing about new Auctioning and winning news what can be used ?

#1 sending messages is not possible

> Notifying users

For sending notification to users about new auctions, you need to use [apprequests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

But apprequests are only for canvas apps, apart from this I don't thing you have a chance of notifying the user, unless you store their emails id and notify them.

Hope this helps